# followUserLocation prop not working for React Native MapView

Tags: react-native

I'm very puzzled by a certain issue I'm having. I'm simulating a freeway drive, and I'm trying to follow the user location. By default this should already be on if showsUserLocation is true. That prop works. However the simulator is not centering on the user location as it moves. In my code below all the props work, except for the followUserLocation... what am I doing wrong?

```
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <MapView
      style={styles.map}
      showsUserLocation={true}
      followUserLocation={true}
      showsCompass={false}
    >
    </MapView>
  </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the flowUserLocation has been broken in react-native until the most recent release (0.19).  Now when I change the location in the Xcode debugger, the map will follow that location.

See comments on the release: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases

And this commit: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/3d0ff69e40f0262e0ffc6f6023ec958b52eeb986